# Typescript AngularJS data binding

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using Typescript with AngularJS 1.4.7 and i got the following code

```
module app.controllers{
    'use strict';

    interface ICustomerScope{
        data: any;
    }

    class CustomerController implements ICustomerScope {
        data: any;
        static $inject = ['GetCustomerSrvc'];
        constructor(GetCustomerSrvc: app.services.ICustomerService){
            var vm = this;
            var data = GetCustomerSrvc.getcustomers();
            vm.Customers= data.Customers;
        }
    }

    angular.module('app').controller('app.controllers.customersCtrl', CustomerController );
}
```

The above code gets the `data.Customers` successfully but i can not bind it to the ng-repeat of my view.

Long story short, how do i bind data in my scope to my view using Typescript.

Hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add a new property on the controller like:

```
class CustomerController implements ICustomerScope {
    data: any;
    customers:any[];

    static $inject = ['GetCustomerSrvc'];
    constructor(GetCustomerSrvc: app.services.ICustomerService){
        var vm = this;
        this.customers = GetCustomerSrvc.getcustomers();
        vm.Customers= data.Customers;
    }
}
```

On you view you can access to vm.Customers, i have a example sharing data from controller to view but wrote in [spanish language](http://goo.gl/VAs9zQ)